# Make thumbs from videos with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

Im try extract small thumbs from video every 15 sec.

Here is what im try now

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -r 1/15 -s 120x90 %03d.jpg
```

But have some error from command line

```
[mjpeg @ 0x9e695c0] bitrate tolerance too small for bitrate
[mjpeg @ 0x9da9a60] ff_frame_thread_encoder_init failed
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Whats wrong here, and how to get thumbs every 15 sec. and save it 0.jpg,1jpg,2jpg,3jpg,4jpg,5jpg...etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example using the [`select`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aselect_002c-select) and [`scale`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input \
-vf "select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,15)',scale=120:-1" \
-vframes vfr -q:v 2 %03d.jpg
```

- The `select` filter can accept [arithmetic expressions](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation). This example will select frames with a minimum distance of 15 seconds.
- `-vsync vfr` prevents repeating frames.
- The `scale` filter is then used to resize the output. Using `scale` instead of `-s` allows you to control when and where the scaling occurs during filtering. Also, instead of forcing specific size you can declare one dimension and use `-1` in the other to make `scale` automatically calculate the correct size to maintain aspect.
- Output quality can be changed with `-q:v`. Effective range is 2-31. A lower value is a higher quality. You can omit this option if you output to PNG.
- FFmpeg development is very active. See the [FFmpeg download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for links to recent `ffmpeg` binaries for Linux, OS X, or Windows.

Also see:

- [FFmpeg Wiki: Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

Comment: Hmm this line working much better than all other, but still can not understand video duration 340 sec. `ffmpeg -i input -vf "select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,60)', \
setpts=N/(25*TB),scale=120:-1" -qscale:v 2 %03d.jpg` this line its created 7 thumbs first is blank...
Why 7 ?

Comment: @MilanMilosevic Impossible to say without the complete ffmpeg console output and possibly the input file to duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Despite what the `man` page says, [ffmpeg doesn't really support fractional frame rates](https://code.google.com/p/ffmbc/issues/detail?id=9) when producing thumbnails from video files. I think your only option may be to generate thumbnails at a rate 1 per second and then simply discard the ones you don't need.</s>

**EDIT:** I'm going to retract that. I tried a frame rate of 1/15 on a file here earlier, and the results didn't look right — the first two thumbnails both showed the video's title page, which only appears for about 2 seconds.

But I just double-checked and is seems that the intervals do actually get closer to 15 seconds thereafter.

I added `-f image2` after the `-s 160x120` switch; I don't know if that made any difference.

Comment: So i can not generate one thumbs every x sec. ?

Comment: That's an old bug report for ffmbc. Did you see if it still applies to recent ffmpeg?

Comment: Looks that is fixed http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=35
im try this one `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f image2 -r 1/60 -s 120x90 thumb_%04d.bmp` but for working strange, its generated 9 thumbs but videos length is 340 sec. first 3 thumbs is blank (black)

Comment: `-f image2` is not required, but it's useful for scripting if your output name is ambiguous.